# Pass parameters from javascript liferay

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, liferay

Using IPC I am calling another portlet

My problem is I want to pass the value from hidden field.

But if I assign jsp scriplets

```
<%! public String projectid= "300015"; %>`

<portlet:param name="projectid" value="<%= projectid%>" />
```

it is working fine.

But I need to pass the value from the hidden field:

```
<input type="text" name="hiddenprojectidBox" id="hiddenprojectidBox">
```

at the place `<%= projectid%>`

Problem solved. It may help others. No need of hidden fields

```
var portletURL = new Liferay.PortletURL('ACTION_PHASE');
            portletURL.setWindowState("maximized");
            portletURL.setPortletId("apseprojectmgmtportlet_WAR_apseprojectmgmtportlet")
            portletURL.setParameter("_spage", "/apse-projectmgmt-portlet/apse-projectmgmt-portlet/projectCostingSheetAction2");
            portletURL.setPortletMode('view');
            portletURL.setParameter("projectid", projectid);
            portletURL.setParameter("limit", 10); 
            portletURL.setParameter("offset", 0);
            document.getElementById('myForm').action =portletURL.toString();
            document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question.

Comment: Since the `portlet:param` is a `JSP taglib` defined by `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>`, then it is evaluated by the `JSP/Servlet` at the server side. Passing the value from hidden field or javascript may not be possible.

Comment: My question is simple.I want to pass  projectid from javascript variable.                                                        <portlet:param name="projectid" value=xxxx />

Comment: i am not sure but you can look at this question..http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2754349

Comment: @PriyaPratheep Can you show the code as to how you are calling the other portlet from the JSP? Like are you using a `renderURL`, `resourceURL` or `actionURL` and how does the `<input>` hidden field comes into the picture while calling the other portlet? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IPC using liferay javascript api then below code could help you,

Calling portlet javascript,

```
Liferay.fire('UPDATE_PROJECT', {
   projectId : A.one('<portlet:namespace />hiddenprojectidBox'),
});
```

Receiving portlet javascript

```
Liferay.on('UPDATE_PROJECT', function(data) {   
   // When event is being executed, getState of the selected countryCode via ajax call     using resourceURL   
   //data.projectId will give the value of the project id passed from calling portlet
} );
```